# How to show the whole column in a text area?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtextarea

I want to show the whole column in the text area from the SQL database but in the TextArea it's only showing last row data. What is the solution?

```
try
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@localhost:1521:XE","tushar","yahoo123");

    st=con.createStatement();

    rs=st.executeQuery("select CUSTOMER_ID from demo_customers" );
        while(rs.next())
        {

        String CUSTOMER_ID  = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");                   

        t2.setText("ID: " + CUSTOMER_ID); //JTextArea t2=new TextArea();

        }

    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{

     System.out.println(e.getMessage());        
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `setText`, you are resetting the contents of the text area. It seems like you are attempting to use it as an additive method. Instead, look into using a `StringBuilder` to build the content, then calling `setText` once.

Comment: `setText(...)` replaces the `TextArea`'s text, you will need to append the new value (ex: `t2.append("ID: " + CUSTOMER_ID);`).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **setting** your text to a new value for each row, you should **append** the new text to the one you previously had. Adding linebreaks might be a good idea as well:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   String CUSTOMER_ID  = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");                   
   t2.append("ID: " + CUSTOMER_ID+"\n");    
}
```

Comment: Don't use a StringBuilder, that will require twice the memory. One for the copy of the data in the StringBuilder and another for the data in the Document. Just append the text directly to the Document.

Comment: @camickr you're right - for large tables that would suck. Removed that.

Comment: (1+) for the append :)